# How to set default value for form fields- Magento?

Tags: php, magento

I have an admin form field(textbox),

```
$fieldset->addField('ajax_time_interval', 'text', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('dealroom')->__('Page Refresh Time Interval'),
          'class'     => 'required-entry',
          'required'  => true,
          'name'      => 'ajax_time_interval',
      ));
```

I need to set a default value for this text field. I tried, setting 'value' => '120', in it. But its not working.

```
$fieldset->addField('ajax_time_interval', 'text', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('dealroom')->__('Page Refresh Time Interval'),
          'class'     => 'required-entry',
          'required'  => true,
          'name'      => 'ajax_time_interval',
          'value'     => '120', 
      ));
```

How to set a defalt value in that field?

Comment: Are you sure something else isn't overwriting it? The code looks fine as I have just done something very similar. Try changing the control name / id to make sure it's unique.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, `setValues()` function was overriding the **'value'** that I had set for the field.

**Cause:**

In my `_prepareForm()` function, I set the value as below:

```
$fieldset->addField('ajax_time_interval', 'text', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('dealroom')->__('Page Refresh Time Interval'),
          'class'     => 'required-entry',
          'required'  => true,
          'name'      => 'ajax_time_interval',
          'value'     => '120', 
      ));
```

At the end of `_prepareForm()` function, there was the following line of code which would reset the form values:

```
$form->setValues($model->getData());
```

**Solution:**

Set model data before `setValues()` function as below:

```
if (!$model->getId()) {
    $model->setData('ajax_time_interval', '120');
}
$form->setValues($model->getData());
```

Comment: I had same issue, and it is solved using your solution. I have used 
if (!$model->getId()) {
    $model->setData('attribute_codel', $this->getRequest()->getParam('attributecode'));
}
$form->setValues($model->getData());

Answer (score 1):

you can do that by adding "default" attribute in field configurations.

```
$fieldset->addField('ajax_time_interval', 'text', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('dealroom')->__('Page Refresh Time Interval'),
          'class'     => 'required-entry',
          'required'  => true,
          'name'      => 'ajax_time_interval',
          'default'     => '120', 
      ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last semicolon....

Check this site help-me a lot:

http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-admin-form-field

Gl mf

Comment: I assume you mean comma `,` Guerra? PHP seems to allow it at the end of the array in any case.